# Rails AWS assets on Cloudfront & s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I setup paperclip to work with S3 to store images on upload. That is working fine.

I then went to add cloudfront for assets (with the code below)

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = ENV['CLOUDFRONT_ENDPOINT']
```

and build the assets, it seems to build all correctly and everything, but whenever I go to the page the links are there

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="http://d2j2dcfn0tfw0d.cloudfront.net/assets/application-ef64d41d2d57abb59ffe5bd71a4f727580ef276a6440e70210cf8d0ab22a6dc2.css" />
<script src="http://d2j2dcfn0tfw0d.cloudfront.net/assets/application-8cd15647254a9c6f940c58bcae0567e6ca66943b8a7576ce87ec903bd19f9937.js"></script>
```

but when I go to that link i get this XML error

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>
assets/application-ef64d41d2d57abb59ffe5bd71a4f727580ef276a6440e70210cf8d0ab22a6dc2.css
</Key>
<RequestId>374DF77BF548DE75</RequestId>
<HostId>
TqrV7id3elsBjugWNkUObG259mU6Vk8MhxcXjrre1qv+XvxGBERDjWoW50iiCyp4
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I looked at my s3 box and it's not there either..

All my cloudfront settings were default except my origin which was my s3 box

Comment: What are you using to copy the assets to s3?

Comment: @FrederickCheung uhh.. nothing.. I guess that's the issue. Could you recommend me something to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cloudfront to fetch your assets from s3 you need to copy the assets to s3. A popular choice for this is the `asset_sync` gen which will do this as part of deploys.

Another option is to let cloudfront fetch the assets from your server - this requires adding a new origin and behaviour to the cloudfront distribution.

Comment: i tried asset_sync but it seems to not be building properly or something.

I also tried letting cloudfront fetch the assets from my server but whenever i build, for about 15-20mins the assets don't show. Other than that it works great